# Reading the XML file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following XML file (parse.xml):

```
<Invoice>
    <InvoiceHeader>
          <Name>cust1</Name>
          <Number>5689</Number>
    </InvoiceHeader>
    <InvoiceHeader>
          <Name>cust1</Name>
          <Number>5689</Number>
          <Number>5459</Number>
    </InvoiceHeader>
<InvoiceHeader>
          <Name>cust1</Name>
          <Number>5689</Number>
          <Number>5645</Number>
          <Number>5879</Number>
    </InvoiceHeader>
</Invoice>
```

I would like to read it into a list of the following class:

```
public class Details    
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<string> Number{get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, in the XML the node `Number` can appear more than one time in `InvoiceHeader`.  I'm not sure how to parse this XML into the `List<Details>` class.

I tried my code:

```
 List<Details> details = new List<Details>;
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load("parse.xml");
 XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Invoice/InvoiceHeader");

 foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
 {
     details.Add(node["Name"].InnerText);
     XmlNodeList dd = node.ChildNodes;

     foreach (XmlNode inch in dd)
     {
         details.Add(node["Number"].InnerText);
     }        
}
```

I know this code isn't right but wanted to show what I have done so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nodeList` is a list of `<InvoiceHeader>` nodes.  One method to solve this problem would be to iterate through the `ChildNodes` of `nodeList` and use the property `Name` to create the  `Details` class in each iteration.

Your code was almost there... I've just updated it slightly so it correctly adds the `<Number>` elements to the list:

```
List<Details> detailsList = new List<Details>();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Invoice/InvoiceHeader");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    // create details class for each InvoiceHeader
    Details detail = new Details();
    detail.Number = new List<string>();

    // loop over child nodes to get Name and all Number elements
    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
    {  
        // check node name to decide how to handle the values               
        if (child.Name == "Name")
        {
            detail.Name = child.InnerText;
        }
        else if (child.Name == "Number")
        {
            detail.Number.Add(child.InnerText);
        }                    
    }
    detailsList.Add(detail);
}
```

Then you can display the results like this:

```
foreach (var details in detailsList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{details.Name}: {string.Join(",", details.Number)}");
}

// output
cust1: 5689
cust1: 5689,5459
cust1: 5689,5645,5879
```

---

Another method you could consider is [Linq-to-Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview).  The below code produces the same output as that above:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var details =  doc.Descendants("Invoice")
                  .Elements()
                  .Select(node => new Details() 
                  { 
                      Name = node.Element("Name").Value, 
                      Number = node.Elements("Number").Select(child => child.Value).ToList() 
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code attachment 
You need to follow this few steps
using System.Xml;
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("file name.xml");

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    // Do some work here on the data.
Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
}
Console.ReadLine();
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    switch (reader.NodeType) 
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
            Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
   Console.WriteLine(">");
            break;
  case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
            Console.WriteLine (reader.Value);
            break;
  case XmlNodeType. EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
            Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
   Console.WriteLine(">");
            break;
    }
}

while (reader.Read()) 
{
       switch (reader.NodeType) 
       {
           case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
               Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);

               while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read the attributes.
                   Console.Write(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
      Console.WriteLine(">");
               break;
     case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
               Console.WriteLine (reader.Value);
               break;
     case XmlNodeType. EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
               Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
      Console.WriteLine(">");
               break;
       }
   }
```

finally save code and run them...
**Complete code listing**

```
using System;
    using System.Xml;

    namespace ReadXMLfromFile
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for Class1.
        /// </summary>
        class Class1
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("file name.xml");
                while (reader.Read()) 
                {
                    switch (reader.NodeType) 
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                            Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine(">");
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                            Console.WriteLine (reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                            Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine(">");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```